# How to obtain $y(1)$ here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y$ be the solution if $y'+y=|x|,x\in \mathbb{R}$ , and $y(-1)=0$ then $y(1)$ equals

(a) $\frac{2}{e}$

(b)$\frac{2}{e^2}$

(c)$2e$

(d) $2e^2 $

Actually here $|x|$ is used in the question so I am finding it difficult to deal with it.I will be required to do cases here? i.e. solution when $x\geq 0$ and when $x<0$

for $x>0$, the equation becomes, $\frac{dy}{dx}+y=x$ on solving its solution is $y=(x-1)+ce^{-x}$

And for $x<0$, the equation becomes $\frac{dy}{dx}+y=-x$ and its solution is $y=(1-x)+c'e^{-x}$, but how to deal further.

Using $y(-1)=0$, in second case, gives $c'=\frac{-2}{e}$

But this will not going to give me $y(1)$...?as I will be required to use the solution of the first case, there $x>0$

Let me know how to go further..

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Observe that $\;C=C'\;$ ... You use this for $\;y(-1)=0\;$ and we're done.

Comment: how to observe both $C=C'$, give some hint..

Answer (score 3):

No need to split in cases to get the solution. The integrating factor is $e^x$, so multiply the equation by it to get $$(e^xy)'=e^xy'+e^x y = e^x|x|$$

so $$e^x y= \int_{-1}^x e^t |t| dt $$ where you choose to integrate from $-1$ because $y(-1)=0$. Then $$y=e^{-x}\int_{-1}^x e^t|t|dt$$

and $$y(1)=e^{-1}\int_{-1}^1 e^t|t|dt=e^{-1}\left(\int_{-1}^0 e^t(-t)dt+\int_{0}^1 e^ttdt\right) = \frac{2(e-1)}{e^2}$$

Comment: not getting your reason why you choose the lower limit as $-1$.

Comment: @mathstudent You may choose a general antiderivative by taking $$\int_a^x e^t |t| dt$$ and then use the condition $y(-1)=0$ to find that $a=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

So far, you have:
\begin{align*}
y=\begin{cases}
ce^{-x}+(x-1)&\text{for }x\geq 0\\
-2e^{-x-1}-(x-1)&\text{for }x\leq 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Now, we know that $y$ is differentiable, because the question mentions $y'$, so $y$ needs to be continuous. Basically, this means we need to check that $y$ does not 'jump' at $x=0$. Therefore, plugging $x=0$ into both expressions, we need:
\begin{align*}
c-1=-2e^{-1}+1
\end{align*}
So $c=2-2e^{-1}$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
y=\begin{cases}
(2-2e^{-1})e^{-x}+(x-1)&\text{for }x\geq 0\\
-2e^{-x-1}-(x-1)&\text{for }x\leq 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
So we can plug in $x=1$ to get $y=(2-e^{-1})e^{-1}=\frac{2}{e}-\frac{2}{e^2}$

I'm not sure where you got those multiple choice options from, but I don't think any of them are correct.